# Error "OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: with an undefined function glutInitWindowPosition"

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl

Does anyone know how to solve this step by step in python
I use i5 8th gen labtop with 256 ssd nvidia ghrafic in my laptop
where is in this error,

- in my python version
- OpenGL version

help me anyone how clearly

try freeglut download and exact folder in easy reade place in c:\ drive and after create new path variable in this pc environmental variable
but not fix this issue
does anyone know this